# How to install a specific version of a package that doesn't show when listing versions?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I am trying to install version `1.11.0` of `tinyproxy`, which seems to be available in the official Ubuntu [repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tinyproxy/1.11.0-1) .

However, when I run `apt install tinyproxy` I only get version `1.10`, and `apt-cache madison tinyproxy` only gives me `1.10` as an option:

```
tinyproxy |   1.10.0-4 | http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

I have tried `apt-get update` and also `apt install tinyproxy=1.11.0-1`, but both fail.

How can I install this version of the package?

edit: This question is not a duplicate of the suggested question, I am not trying to install a version that is already available in a repository, I am trying to understand why the version is not available in my repository when it is listed as avilable online.

Comment: A **1.11.0** for `libc6 (>= 2.17)`   is available from Debian 12 → `sudo apt install ./tinyproxy-bin_1.11.0-1_amd64.deb ./tinyproxy_1.11.0-1_all.deb` .... Download links http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tinyproxy/tinyproxy-bin_1.11.0-1_amd64.deb ... and http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tinyproxy/tinyproxy_1.11.0-1_all.deb ........ Ubuntu 20.04 was used for the install of tinyproxy_1.11.0 .

Comment: @Nmath unfortunately, no, since I mentioned this version doesn't seem to even appear on `apt` for me, I am trying to understand why and make it show up.